# Independent and dependent clause of

Tags: grammar

I plant vegetables.
I need to see if it is a phrase or independent or dependent

Answer (score 1):

It is independent because it does not require any other phrase to make sense. It also fulfills the SVO or subject-predicate models for a complete phrase/sentence. Even *"I plant"* would be considered independent under the right circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

I plant vegetables. This is independent clause because it has its own subject ( I ) and predicate ; verb (plant) and object ( vegetables) . As it delivers the complete message without depending on any other clause or phrase. So , independent clauses itself are complete clauses. Here are some more examples:
He ran.
She cooks meal.
It rains.
I ate.